# T-SQL equivalent to oracle show all

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

what is sqlserver T-SQL equivalent to oracles "show all" listing the set parms on the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select @@options
```

see http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1415 for how to decode this.

Comment: Thank martin useful link, Bring back Oracle all is forgiven this so long winded

Comment: Martin you have answered this question the tick thing won't work

Comment: also, `DBCC USEROPTIONS`. Can use `INSERT...EXEC ('DBCC USEROPTIONS')` to grab the values.

Comment: Thanks Peter Mucho Grando just what I needed.

Comment: How did you know his middle and last names were Mucho Grando?